# Simulate accumulation of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm animating several image element children within a div container `holder`... they will gradually fall from the top to the bottom of the screen

I want to simulate accumulation... Meaning, if an image intersects another, it will lay on top of it and stop moving (picture snow falling and accumulating)

The way I thought to do this is iterate through each child image and animate its location... then loop through each sibling and check if there is an intersection... but of course this double loop provides terrible performance... Any thoughts?

```
function update () {
            var myInterval = null;
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            myInterval = setInterval(function() {
                $("#holder > img").each(function() {    
                    $(this).css({top: $(this).position().top+=3});  

                    var $el = $(this); //bind context
                    $el.siblings().each(function() {
                        if ($el.position().top >= $(this).position().top) {
                            log("INTERSECT");
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 10);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider:

1. It seems you are trying to make the animation yourself, step by step. It might be easier to use jQuery's .[animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead.
2. No need to check for intersections when the layout engine can do that for you. Just put the images where they need to be but in a way in which they are not initially visible. For example, `position: relative;` and `bottom: someVeryBigNumber;`. Then animate them to their final place.

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="droppableWrapper">
        <div class="droppable"></div>
        <div class="droppable"></div>
        <div class="droppable"></div>
        <div class="droppable"></div>
        <div class="droppable"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#droppableWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.droppable {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1000px; /* Enough to be out of the screen */
}
```

```javascript
var stack = new Array();

$(".droppable").each(function(){
    // Note that the order of the stack 
    // is the inverse of the visual "stack" effect.
    stack.push(new Droppable($(this)));
});

startDropping();

function startDropping(){
    dropNext();
}

function dropNext(){
    var droppable = stack.pop();
    if(droppable){
        droppable.drop().done(dropNext);
    }
}

function Droppable(domElem) {
    function drop(){
        return domElem.animate({
            bottom :"0px"
        },{
            duration: 1000
        }).promise();
    }
    this.drop = drop;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/uycefdLj/)**

And a fancier one, using jQuery UI, in case this is what you're looking for: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/ezfocf2o/1/)**

Comment: abl I don't see how this detects where sibling elements are such that if one is encountered, it can stop moving and 'accumulate' on top

Comment: @Growler this code does _not_ detect where elements are, or when do they collide, because it doesn't need to. The layout engine (i.e. the browser) does this work. You just define a series of elements and the browser will neatly place them one on top of the other, just like this comment is exactly below yours even though there is no Javascript code in SO that calculates the height of your comment.

Comment: Okay but if you want elements to stack in a non linear manner, let's say snow fall, that's what I'm going for